# What are ways to optimize scripts on js?

Tags: javascript, optimization

I noticed, that JS scripts consum a lot of RAM. Particularly, client side `socket.io + node.js`.

What are ways to optimize scripts on js?
What to look for in the first time and what do standards exist?

Comment: Those tools have been tested and used in many applications. If you have written a slow application you can't blame them. What makes you think that those are the culprits?

Comment: How does node consume memory on the client side?

Comment: Are you noticing the high memory consumption on the client, the server or both sides?

Comment: Only on client JS. Now on client side node consume 138 mb(Chrome)

Comment: Umm, node runs on the server, not the client.

Comment: I had wrote, that on client side there is a socket.io js, not Node.js

Comment: In your question you wrote "client side `socket.io + node.j`. Then in a comment you wrote "on client side node consume(s) 138MB". Then in another comment you wrote, "on client side, there is...not node.js". So do you think node is, or is not, on the client? Please clarify your understanding by either editing your question, or writing one clear comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: you do not need to optimize your scripts, at least not until you have a clear, overriding reason to do so. JS scripts consume as much memory as they consume. The engine manages memory and garbage collects. There is nothing specific you can do to reduce memory consumption other than processing less data, or using fewer libraries. 138MB is not a horribly large footprint, why does that bother you? If you decide that you really have nothing better to worry about than memory usage, then run a profile using your favorite browser devtools. However, if the usage is in someone else's code, and not your own, then there's not really anything you can do except, as I said, get rid of their code and do without it, or replace it with something else.

Not clear what you intend to mean by "what do standards exist". What kind of standards do you refer to? Do you mean best practices? Best practices, as I said, are not to worry about this, unless you are a library author and are trying to optimize your own library, OR, if you suspect a memory leak, which does occur but less frequently than one might think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some compressor to minification, sometimes I use the grunt properties or https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS, or you can do it online here http://jscompress.com

If you have to many files.js to import, you can use requireJs to manage it. http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score -3):

Add the scripts to bottom of the html content or can load the script asynchronously.